# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've been trying to build this blog app, Before is fine and in the dev environment is also fine. But, as soon as i try to build it for production it caught in this error.

> Error occurred prerendering page "/blogs/[slug]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I am confused because this app had been build before and nothing is wrong. This is the culprit:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import moment from "moment";

const Post = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{posts && posts.title}</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        ></meta>
      </Head>
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "3.85rem" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <h1>{posts.title}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-end">
          <p style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
            {moment(posts.dateTime).format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY, hh:mm:ss a")}
          </p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img
            className="postThumbNail"
            src={posts.thumbnail.url}
            alt={posts.thumbnail.url}
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <ReactMarkdown>{posts.body}</ReactMarkdown>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://someapi.com/blogs?slug=${slug}`
  );
  const blogPost = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts: blogPost[0],
    },
    revalidate: 600,
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Get Post From Strapi
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://someapi.com/blogs"
  );
  const post = await res.json();
  //  Retrun Enrich Content
  return {
    paths: post.map((posts) => ({
      params: { slug: String(posts.slug) },
    })),
    fallback: true,
  };
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: You checked if posts exists here: `<title>{posts && posts.title}</title>`, but forgot to do it here: `<h1>{posts.title}</h1>`

Comment: @NicholasTower Yep Sure, But now the problem is goes to post.dateTime, I mean the conditional did help but shall I do that for all? Is there any more graceful way of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1**
You need to check if attribute exists first with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) :

```
  <h1>{posts?.title}</h1>
```

**Solution 2**
or object is not null `return null` until data loads

```
if(!posts) return null

return <div> ...Code </div>
```

Comment: I attempted this for my implementation and it did not work. Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/73368354/13374074 seemed to do it for me!

Answer (score 3):

The issue occurs because you're using `fallback: true` in `getStaticPaths`, and you're not handling the fallback page which gets served by Next.js before `getStaticProps` finishes running. At that point the props passed to the page component will be empty.

> In the “fallback” version of a page:
>
> - The page’s props will be empty.
> - Using the [router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), you can detect if the fallback is being rendered, `router.isFallback` will be `true`.
>
> — [Next.js, Fallback Pages documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-pages)

---

##### #1 Handle fallback page with `router.isFallback`

You can properly handle the fallback version of the page using `router.isFallback`.

```js
const Post = ({ posts }) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    // Display loading until `getStaticProps()` finishes running, and populates the props.
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return (
        <h1>{posts.title}</h1>
    );
};
```

---

##### #2 Use `fallback: 'blocking'` instead

As an alternative, if you don't really need the fallback functionality, you can change the fallback value in `getStaticPaths` to [`fallback: 'blocking'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-blocking). This will still generate new pages like `fallback: true`, but will wait until `getStaticProps` has ran before rendering the page.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const res = await fetch("https://someapi.com/blogs");
    const post = await res.json();

    return {
        paths: post.map((posts) => ({
            params: { slug: String(posts.slug) }
        })),
        fallback: 'blocking'
    };
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution! Especially the two potential implementations!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Head>
        <title>{posts && posts.title}</title>
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        ></meta>
      </Head>
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: "3.85rem" }}>
        <div className="row">
          <h1>{posts && posts.title}</h1> // You've just forgot that if posts exist condition
        </div>
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-end">
          <p style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
            {moment(posts.dateTime).format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY, hh:mm:ss a")}
          </p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img
            className="postThumbNail"
            src={posts.thumbnail.url}
            alt={posts.thumbnail.url}
          />
        </div>
        <br />
        <ReactMarkdown>{posts && posts.body}</ReactMarkdown>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thx Dude, But now the problem is goes to `post.dateTime`, I mean the conditional did help but shall I do that for all? Is there any more graceful way of solving this?

Comment: Check Chemi's solution. It is called optional chaining which comes from typescript, less code, and looks better. `posts && posts.title === posts?.title`